# AMQ9641: Remote CipherSpec error for channel IBM WebSphere MQ client 8.0.0.9

Tags: ibm-mq

I am running below command from (commandline only not web client) Webspere MQ client v 8.0.0.9 and i am not able to connect MQ server

```
/opt/mqm/samp/bin/amqsgetc Q-name Q-manager
```

i am exporting

```
export MQCHLTAB=xxx.TAB                   ---------xxx.TAB under /var/mqm
export MQCHLLIB=/var/mqm
export MQSSLKEYR=/var/mqm/ssl/cms/cert     -------- cert.kdb under cms dir using
export MQSERVER=channel-name/TCP/'xx.xx.xx.xx(xxx)'
```

Error i am getting is

```
07/04/2018 09:22:20 AM - Process(6024.1) User(username) Program(amqsgetc)
                    Host(hostname) Installation(Installation1)
                    VRMF(8.0.0.9) QMgr(.)

AMQ9641: Remote CipherSpec error for channel 'ch-name' to host
'MQ-server-ip(port)'.

EXPLANATION:
The remote end of channel 'ch-name' on host 'MQ-server-ip(port)' has had
a CipherSpec error. The channel did not start.
ACTION:
Review the error logs on the remote system to discover the problem with the
CipherSpec.
----- cmqxrfpt.c : 573 --------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: yes i am using CCDT and both side cert are same

Comment: Thanks, its working now !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is to remove the `MQSERVER` environment variable.  For further details and references read below.

---

If you specify the `MQSERVER` environment variable MQ will only use this information and ignore the the CCDT environment variables (`MQCHLLIB` and `MQCHLTAB`).

This is referenced in the IBM MQ Knowledge Center page [Configuring > Configuring connections between the server and clients > Using IBM MQ environment variables > MQSERVER > Using MQSERVER](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.con.doc/q017020_.htm).

> If you use the MQSERVER environment variable to define the channel
>   between your IBM® MQ MQI client machine and a server machine, this is
>   the only channel available to your application, and no reference is
>   made to the client channel definition table (CCDT).

---

Further information on how MQ application will determine connection details is referenced in the IBM MQ Knowledge Center page [Developing applications > Developing MQI applications with IBM MQ > Writing client procedural applications > Running applications in the IBM MQ MQI client environment > Connecting IBM MQ MQI client applications to queue managers](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q027440_.htm)

> When an application running in an IBM MQ client environment issues an
>   MQCONN or MQCONNX call, the client identifies how it is to make the
>   connection. When an MQCONNX call is issued by an application on an IBM
>   MQ client, the MQI client library searches for the client channel
>   information in the following order:
>
> 1. Using the contents of the ClientConnOffset or ClientConnPtr fields of the MQCNO structure (if supplied). These fields identify the
>      channel definition structure (MQCD) to be used as the definition of
>      the client connection channel. Connection details can be overridden by
>      using a pre-connect exit. For more information, see Referencing
>      connection definitions using a pre-connect exit from a repository.
> 2. If the MQSERVER environment variable is set, the channel it defines is used.
> 3. If an mqclient.ini file is defined and contains a ServerConnectionParms, the channel that it defines is used. For more
>      information, see Configuring a client using a configuration file and
>      CHANNELS stanza of the client configuration file.
> 4. If the MQCHLLIB and MQCHLTAB environment variables are set, the client channel definition table they point to is used.
> 5. If an mqclient.ini file is defined and contains ChannelDefinitionDirectory and ChannelDefinitionFile attributes, these
>      attributes are used to locate the client channel definition table. For
>      more information, see Configuring a client using a configuration file
>      and CHANNELS stanza of the client configuration file.
> 6. Finally, if the environment variables are not set, the client searches for a client channel definition table with a path and name
>      that are established from the DefaultPrefix in the mqs.ini file. If
>      the search for a client definition table fails, the client uses the
>      following paths:
>
>    - UNIX and Linux systems: /var/mqm/AMQCLCHL.TAB
>    - Windows: C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere MQ\amqclchl.tab
>    - IBM i: /QIBM/UserData/mqm/@ipcc
>    - IBM MQ Appliance: _AMQCLCHL.TAB. They appear under the mqbackup:// URI.

---

You cannot specify Cipherspec using the `MQSERVER` environment variable.  This is referenced in the IBM MQ Knowledge Center page [Configuring > Configuring connections between the server and clients > Using IBM MQ environment variables > MQSERVER](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.con.doc/q016990_.htm)

> MQSERVER environment variable is used to define a minimal channel.
>   MQSERVER specifies the location of the IBM® MQ server and the
>   communication method to be used.
>
> You cannot use MQSERVER to define an SSL channel or a channel with
>   channel exits. For details of how to define an SSL channel, see
>   Protecting channels with SSL.

Comment: for another q i am getting  MQOPEN ended with reason code 2035
unable to open queue for output
Sample AMQSPUT0 end

Comment: 2035 is a very common problem and not related to the original question.  Search for: `[ibm-mq] 2035` for existing answers on the subject.  The queue manager error logs should provide you a clear reason for the problem.

Comment: yes got it this related to user level authentication from client to server.

Comment: one more last question  I am trying to connect MQ server using java app and i am getting SSL error  " Caused by: com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException: CC=2;RC=2393;AMQ9771: SSL handshake failed."    and .jks file has TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 cipherspec & and i am using java 8    where i missed something.

Comment: Probably strong encryption provider is not installed?

Comment: i uncomment crypto.policy=unlimited in java.security Java8 its works !

Answer (score 0):

uncomment crypto.policy=unlimited in java.security Java8 its work for me !